# Autocast sealed sub class fails - why? Rx Java 2 Observable Stream onErrorReturn

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, viewmodel, rx-java2

I want to finish this year with understanding something that wasn't clear to my parts of this year.

We are using sub-classes of sealed classes to give feedback back from our ViewModel to the UI.

So we start with something like:

```
sealed class LoginRoute {

    object LoginSuccessful : LoginRoute()

    object LoginFailed : LoginRoute()

    data class LoginError(val error: Throwable) : LoginRoute()
}
```

Within our ViewModel we have some rxJava2 streams, for instance:

```
override val loginServiceStatusStream: Observable<LoginRoute> =
    loginServiceStatus
        .map { status ->
            if (status == Status.OK) {
                LoginSuccessful
            } else {
                LoginFailed
            }
        }
        .onErrorReturn {
            LoginError(it)
        }
```

What we actually experience: The above shown Observable doesn't compile because as soon as `onErrorReturn` is added we have to **manually add a cast to LoginRoute** for each mapped return value.

Like:

```
override val loginServiceStatusStream: Observable<LoginRoute> =
    loginServiceStatus
        .map { status ->
            if (status == Status.OK) {
                LoginSuccessful as LoginRoute
            } else {
                LoginFailed as LoginRoute
            }
        }
        .onErrorReturn {
            LoginError(it)
        }
```

If we just do it like that (**without** `onErrorReturn`) everything **works without** the additional **cast** statement:

```
override val loginServiceStatusStream: Observable<LoginRoute> =
    loginServiceStatus
        .map { status ->
            if (status == Status.OK) {
                LoginSuccessful
            } else {
                LoginFailed
            }
        }
```

I would really like to understand why this cast is necessary.

Comment: I just tried this in IntelliJ with Kotlin 1.3.10 and rxJava2 (v2.2.4) and it compiled, even with `onErrorReturn`, without needing the cast. What versions of everything are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I'll work on a working sample next year, starting January 7th.
Merry Christmas && a happy new year :)